# Function to print a list of background processes in C (like jobs)?

Tags: c, bash, shell

I'm trying to make a simple shell in C, but have learned that it cannot handle the "jobs" command. I've tried doing

```
execlp("jobs", "jobs", (char *) 0);
```

But that returns "execlp: No such file or directory".

In bash i've tried doing

```
$ which jobs
```

But that says it cannot find jobs in any of my PATH folders. 
I can use the jobs command just fine in bash, but cannot find the execution file so I can use execlp on it in my shell.

Is this just a bash function that I can't implement or is there a separate function in C to do this?

Comment: You are correct that there is no external command or C API to do the work of `jobs` because `jobs` is a command built in to the shell.  But that does not mean you "can't implement" it.  That actually means that you'll *have to* implement it, and not just outsource its functionality to an external program.

Comment: If you keep track of jobs as you create them (and as they terminate), then its trivial to implement the report.

Comment: Alright, yeah that's what I figured. Just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing out on any functions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jobs` is a bash builtin, and you can't exec it from a C program.

What you can do is to keep the PIDs of created childs:

```
pid_t child_pids[1000], f;
int child_nb=0;

f = fork();
if (f < 0) { perror ("fork"); exit (1); }

if (f == 0) { // child
    // do the child stuff
    exit (0);
}

// Parent
child_pids[child_nb++] = f;
```

To update your child list you can receive SIGCHLD and call `waitpid(-1,NULL,WNOHANG)`.

Comment: it's seems to me correct as far I know. But, if you extend your answer with the `jobs` functionality, it is more clear.